# How can I make pagination of a findorfail method in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this function in my controller which is the output of many animals and I would like to paginate it. How am I to do that

controller

```
public function show($id)
{
    $farms = User::with(['animals'])->findOrFail($id);
    return view('slaughter.show',compact('farms'));
}
```

Is there any other way of doing that because I have tried to add the paginate method at the end and I am getting an error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to paginate a "has many" relationship that is ordered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507581/how-to-paginate-a-has-many-relationship-that-is-ordered)

Answer (score 0):

`paginate()` is a method on the Query Builder instance while `findOrFail()` returns an Eloquent model, and in this case a single instance, as it is for a single user by the given `$id`.

You can maybe query the animals through their own model, and paginate it, like this:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $farms = Animal::where('user_id', $id)->paginate(10);
    return view('slaughter.show',compact('farms'));
}
```

Comment: This the error I am getting "Call to a member function paginate() on null"

Comment: This `Animal::where('user_id', $id)` does not returns null 100% :) so you are using something different then..

Comment: Let me try to dd it

Answer (score 0):

I would do this to get a paginated collection of animals for the User. Dependency Injection in the show method as well assuming you also require some user data on the slaughter page.

```
 public function show(User $user)
{
    $farms = Animals::where('user_id', $user->id)->paginate();
    return view('slaughter.show',compact('farms', 'user'));
}
```

Your route will need updating, something like this...

```
Route::get('animals/{user}', 'AnimalsController@show')
```

Comment: I am getting an error "call paginate method using on null

Comment: Probably your route needs updating, probably still has {id} in it so the DI won't work. Update to have {user}. Updated my answer above.