# How to add pagination to relation in laravel 7 controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

How can I add pagination to model relation in my controller? Here's my case :

```
public function show($movie) {
       $movie = Movie::find($movie);
       $episodes = $movie->episodes;
       $genre = $movie->genre;

       return view('layout.detailMovie', compact('movie', 'episodes', 'genre'));
}
```

I want to add pagination for the $episodes. Where do I have to put the "->paginate()" code?

Comment: Try `$movie->episodes()->paginate(10);`

Comment: it says method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist, but when I import use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection, it is not used by the paginate(). What should i add to the controller?

Comment: Are you sure you've used `$movie->episodes()->paginate()` and not `episodes->paginate()` ?

Comment: Don't forget to add `()` to `episodes`

Comment: oh, yeah, it's my mistake, sorry guys, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: so the episodes() represent function episodes() in my model? and the pagination work from there?

Comment: Yes. That's how it works.

Comment: Please note, your question title is confusing. It should be something like, **How to add pagination to relation in laravel 7 controller?**

Comment: okay, thank you for the advice and for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
public function show($movie) {
       $movies = Movie::with('episodes', 'genre')->where('movie', $movie)->paginate(3);

       return view('layout.detailMovie', compact('movies'));
}
```

**In Blade**

```
{{ $products->links() }}  OR {{ $products->render() }}
```

**You can fetch data in blade like**

```
foreach($movies as $movie) {}
   //your code
}


foreach($movies->episodes as $episodes) {}
   //your code
}

foreach($movies->genre as $genre) {}
   //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Movie::find($movie)->with('episodes')->paginate(3);
```

or:

```
$reports = User::find($user->id)
        ->reports()
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->paginate($paginate);
    return $reports;
```

if that doesnt work look at this :
[How to paginate a "has many" relationship that is ordered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507581/how-to-paginate-a-has-many-relationship-that-is-ordered)

Comment: //by the way if you are finding 1 movie, why are you paginating that?